# Pandas explode in a nested list

Tags: python, pandas

Given the example code below

```
listb = [[[1,2] , [2,3]] ,[ [3,4] , [5,6]]]
listc =[[9 , 7 ],[8 , 10] ]
lista = zip(listb , listc)
x = pandas.DataFrame(lista ,columns = ['A' , 'B'])
x.explode(['A' ,'B'])
```

I want to explode

```
       A               B
[[1,2] , [2,3]]      [9,7]

[[3,4] , [5,6]]      [8,10]
```

as

```
  A         B
[1,2]      [9]
[2,3]      [7]
[3,4]      [8]
[5,6]      [10]
```

but when I do this pandas doesn't perform any action on the dataframe .

Comment: What do you currently get? Which pandas version do you have? Is the issue that you get a scalar in B instead of a list?

Comment: no i dont get anything thats the problem . Literally no change.

Comment: What about the pandas version? This works fine for me

Comment: I have 1.3.5 installed

Comment: By "no change," do you mean `x` does not change? How about `x = x.explode(['A' ,'B'])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected (*NB. [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) handle multiple columns since pandas 1.3.0*):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[[1, 2], [2, 3]],
                         [[3, 4], [5, 6]]],
                   'B':  [[9, 7], [8, 10]]})

out = df.explode(['A' ,'B'])

#         A   B
# 0  [1, 2]   9
# 0  [2, 3]   7
# 1  [3, 4]   8
# 1  [5, 6]  10
```

Only if you really want to keep lists in B, add:

```
out['B'] = out['B'].apply(lambda x: [x])
```

output:

```
        A     B
0  [1, 2]   [9]
0  [2, 3]   [7]
1  [3, 4]   [8]
1  [5, 6]  [10]
```